# Firebase Saving Data Methods Asynchronous or Synchronous

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

Are firebase saving data methods such as childByAutoId and updateChildValues asynchronous or synchronous? There seems to be no place to pass in a completion handler so I'm guessing they are synchronous but I'm not sure because it seems a little weird (for performance purposes) that Firebase would make such commonly needed methods synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

As with almost all of the modern web, interacting with the Firebase Database is an asynchronous operation. That's why most methods in the Firebase Database API can take a completion block.

For write operations the block is sometimes optional, because there are cases when you may not want to specify a completion block.

For example, here's the API reference doc for `updateChildValues:withCompletionBlock`:

> `updateChildValues:withCompletionBlock:`
>
> SWIFT
>
> `func updateChildValues(values: [NSObject : AnyObject], withCompletionBlock block: (NSError?, FIRDatabaseReference) -> Void)`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *values* - A dictionary of the keys to change and their new values
>
> *block* - The block that is triggered after the update has been written on the Firebase Database servers

The `childByAutoId` method is a client-side operation; it does not need to interact with the Firebase servers, which is one of the reasons it can run when the user is not connected to the database. Since it doesn't need to interact with the server, it is synchronous and immediately return a reference to the new location, which is guaranteed to be unique. If you want to learn more about the keys that are generated by `childByAutoId`, read this blog post [The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).